# Insert date and time into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, insert-id

I am trying to insert date and time into mysql datetime field. When a user select a date and time, it will generate two POST variables. I have searched internet but still not sure how to do it.

My code.

```
//date value is 05/25/2010
//time value is 10:00

$date=$_POST['date'];
$time=$_POST['time'];

$datetime=$date.$time
```

If I insert $datetime into mysql, the date appears to be 0000-00-00:00:00:00

I appreciate it if anyone could help me about this. Thanks.

Comment: +1 to all reply! Thanks GSTo's answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$datetime = $_POST['date'] . ' ' . $_POST['time'] . ':00';
$datetime = mysql_real_escape_string($datetime);
$query = "INSERT INTO table(timestamp) VALUES ('$datetime')";
```

alternative solution that can handle more formats:

```
$datetime = $_POST['date'] . ' ' . $_POST['time'];
$datetime = mysql_real_escape_string($datetime);
$datetime = strtotime($datetime);
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$datetime);
$query = "INSERT INTO table(timestamp) VALUES ('$datetime')";
```

Comment: Because the first snippet contains an SQL injection vulnerability. One more -1 from me. :-P :-)

Comment: @Noninlist - code snippets from StackOverflow shouldn't be cut n paste verbatim. I addressed the problem at hand. but just for you, i added a call to mysql real escape string

Answer (score 4):

Date must have format shown to you: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

So, you have to convert it. There are thousand questions about this conversion here on SO.
The shortest way is like

```
list($m,$d,$y) = explode("/",$_POST['date']);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string("$y-$m-$d ".$_POST['time']);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the datetime format looks like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

so you've got to format your $datetime to look like that. And in your query that needs to be encapsulated in quoation marks.

Answer (score 2):

- Either you transform the string to be in the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format yourself,
- or you use the `str_to_date()` function from MySQL.

  INSERT INTO table DATETIME values (str_to_date($date,"%m/%d/%Y %h:%i"))

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, by default, Mysql datetime should be in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format.

Answer (score 0):

I have added date and time in mysql db via API like this:

---

Call API

`http://localhost/SendOrder.php?odate=20120323&otime=164545`

1. `odate` type is DATE
2. `otime` type is TIME in DB.

---

It will store odate as 2012-03-23 and otime as 16:45:45.